How to only allow wireguard clients, bypass all other connections
I am not a pro or anything in networking. I copied a bunch of commands and snippets to set up wireguard with wg-easy docker container. Wireguard in all the clients have standalone installation (not wg-easy). Here's my server config (in wg-easy). (Let's call this server 'Main Server')
[Interface]
PrivateKey = [REDACTED]
Address = 10.8.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
PreUp =
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 51820 -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT;
PreDown =
PostDown =

## Configs for peers including Computer A


Important to note here that I have pihole also installed in a docker container within the wireguard 'server'. Pihole's ip is 10.2.0.100 (for DNS)
Next, one of the wireguard 'clients' serves as a selfhosted server. Let's call this 'Computer A'. I don't want adblocking through pihole and stuff. I just want this client to act as a server (with caddy). For this wireguard 'client' I have this configs:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = [REDACTED]
Address = 10.8.0.3/24
DNS = 10.2.0.100
MTU = 1600

PreUp = ip route add 10.2.0.100 via 192.168.100.1 dev wlx00
PostDown = ip route del 10.2.0.100 via 192.168.100.1 dev wlx00
PostUp = ip rule add table 200 from 192.168.100.200
PostUp = ip route add table 200 default via 192.168.100.1
PreDown = ip rule delete table 200 from 192.168.100.200
PreDown = ip route delete table 200 default via 192.168.100.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = [REDACTED]
PresharedKey = [REDACTED]
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
PersistentKeepalive = 0
Endpoint = [WG_SERVER_IP]:51820


This part of the configs are copied from DigitalOcean's wireguard installation page. Important to note here that I have set the MTU to high or else the selfhosted services could not be accessed. 192.168.100.1 is Computer A's default gateway and wlx00 is the wireless network that Computer A is connected to. 192.168.100.200 is Computer A's static IP inside wlx00 network.
Now, everything works fine. But when I pull docker images inside Computer A, they are always timing out. Several people had the same problem as per docker support forum. This problem could be mitigated by lowering the MTU values. However, lowering the MTU values would stop me from accessing the sefhosted services. (I have no idea why this happens and I don't want to spend time in investigating. Instead I want a different solution...)
I want to allow the peers connected to Main Server to access the selfhosted services in Computer A. All other packets from/to Computer A must be bypassed from Wireguard. I guess it has something to do with AllowedIPs setting. I tried setting AllowedIPs to 10.8.0.1/16 but no luck.
I am sure there is a simpler way to do this. Please help!

Yes, AllowedIPs basically says "send everything in these addresses to the peer matching this key" (you can have multiple peer blocks). To only send traffic addressed to other wireguard clients through the tunnel, set AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.0/24 in the client config under [Peer]. Add ,10.2.0.100/32 there too if you want to include DNS on the tunnel, otherwise remove DNS = 10.2.0.100 at the top and the route.

@Cpt.Whale yes, I tried that. I can't seem to access that client from other clients. I must be missing something. Any idea?

Are the other clients able to access it when you change AllowedIPs back?  If so, double-check that the source IPs for those clients are in the allowed range. Are they accessing it by name or IP?

Yes, the other clients can access when AllowedIPs are reverted back. All the clients are in the range 10.8.0.0/24.
